# How to sort xml folders and files by their attribute value using xsl?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

First of all, I'm noob when it comes to xsl.
I have one .xml document that is not in proper order.

xml example:

```
<folder-one order="2">
    <another-folder order="2">
        <some-file order="2">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="1">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="3">title</some-file>
    </another-folder>
    <another-folder order="1">
        <some-file order="2">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="1">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="3">title</some-file>
    </another-folder>
</folder-one>

<folder-two order="1">
    <another-folder order="2">
        <some-file order="2">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="1">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="3">title</some-file>
    </another-folder>
    <another-folder order="1">
        <some-file order="2">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="1">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="3">title</some-file>
    </another-folder>
</folder-two>
```

And I need this:

```
<folder-one order="1">
    <another-folder order="1">
        <some-file order="1">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="2">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="3">title</some-file>
    </another-folder>
    <another-folder order="2">
        <some-file order="1">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="2">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="3">title</some-file>
    </another-folder>
</folder-one>

<folder-two order="2">
    <another-folder order="1">
        <some-file order="1">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="2">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="3">title</some-file>
    </another-folder>
    <another-folder order="2">
        <some-file order="1">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="2">title</some-file>
        <some-file order="3">title</some-file>
    </another-folder>
</folder-two>
```

Whatever I try to do, I mess things up and can't even display the structure.
I've tried using xsl:for-each and xsl:sort but it didn't help. Probably because I'm not doing it right. I don't know what else to do..

Here is the xsl that is already there. And changing it in anyway causes me trouble..

```
<xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ectd = "http://www.ich.org/ectd"  
xmlns:xlink = "http://www.w3c.org/1999/xlink">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="util/style/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>eCTD <font size="-1"> DTD version <xsl:value-of select="/ectd:ectd/@dtd-version"/></font></h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/ectd:ectd/*"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <ul type="square">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <font color="green">
                <xsl:if test="@manufacturer != ''"> [manufacturer: <xsl:value-of select="@manufacturer"/>] </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="@substance != ''"> [substance: <xsl:value-of select="@substance"/>] </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="@product-name != ''"> [product name: <xsl:value-of select="@product-name"/>] </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="@dosageform != ''"> [dosage form: <xsl:value-of select="@dosageform"/>] </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="@indication != ''"> [indication: <xsl:value-of select="@indication"/>] </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="@excipient != ''"> [excipient: <xsl:value-of select="@excipient"/>] </xsl:if>
            </font>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="leaf">
    <ul type="square">
        <li>
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <font color="red">
                [<xsl:value-of select="@operation"/>]
            </font>
        </li>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node-extension">
    <ul type="square">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="leaf|node-extension"/>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</xsl:template>
```

"leaf" is "some-file" in my example....

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: Are the elements in your actual XML input really named "folder-one" and "folder-two", or "folder" both?

Comment: No, they are not named folder-one, folder-two... I'm actually scanning documentations and getting folder names and files that users used.

Comment: There, I have added the xsl file that's troubling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `xsl:sort` instruction to the famous [identity transform template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="@order" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that your XML example is **not** a well-formed document: you are missing a root element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try that. And this was just the middle part (example) of my .xml. It has a root element

Comment: This works but unfortunately it conflicts with xsl that is already in there

Comment: That's too bad; unfortunately, my crystal ball is at the cleaners. My guess is that you need to add the sort instruction to one (or more) of the apply-templates elements you have - in the same manner as shown in my template above. In order to be sure, I would have to re-write your XML to match your XSLT (or the other way around) - and that's not something I am about to do.

Comment: Of course, I don't expect you to do that :) Thanks a lot for your help. I wish I could thumb you up but I'm new so I can't. Sorry